# RegEX for numbers only and also mask format for money

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking for RegEX for numbers only and also for a money format ($xxx.xx)

I currently use this peice of code for numbers and letters and it works just fine:

```
function validateForOnlyLettersAndNums(txt) 
{ txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r]+/g, ''); }
```

However, when i looked around the web for what i am asking here, i only find stuff like this:

```
(?<=\s|^)-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?=\s|$)
```

And it doesn't seem to work when i use that in the code here:

```
function validateForOnlyNums(txt)
{ txt.value = txt.value.replace(?<=\s|^)-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?=\s|$, ''); }
```

Comment: That second regex seems **way** overcomplicated. What's wrong with `.replace(/[^ 0-9\n\r]+/g, '')`?

Comment: @MattBall: Your code worked! Thanks! Do you happen to have one that masks for a price? ($xxx.xx)?

Comment: You seem to be trying to do two different things. Why is a "validate" function removing characters?

Comment: Ill need 2 separate functions.. One for numbers only and the other for only currency format. I just showed an example of what i currently had in regards to the only numbers part.

Answer (score 1):

You have not surrounded your 2nd regex in forward slashes, i.e:

```
function validateForOnlyNums(txt)
{ txt.value = txt.value.replace(/?<=\s|^)-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?=\s|$/, ''); }
```

Comment: When using that code you posted i get the error **SyntaxError: invalid quantifier** and its pointing to the start of **/?<**

Comment: Also, it's missing a `(` before `?<=\s|^)`. Also, it's missing a `)` after `(?=\s|$`. Also, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds anyway `(?<=\s|^)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function validateForOnlyNums(txt)
{
    txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^$0-9\.]/g, '');
}
```

it should replace anything unlike $xxx.xx where x is a digit with an empty string. The only drawback with this one is that it will also accept input like $12..3.5$7.

Comment: That does not seem to work. I'm able to input characters into the box.

Comment: Is there a way to take out a **$** and **.00** if it does not have any cents?

Comment: Yes, but that would involve a more complex regular expression, probably using lookaheads. There are sites like http://www.regextester.com/ where you can test them.